# How to connect in Django after Oracle Database upgrade from 11g to 19c

Tags: python, django, oracle

My database was changed from 11g to oracle 19c, with that I used the form of authentication using "SID", the error I was getting was ORA-12505. Currently the database connection uses the form "Service Name". When changing the information in the Python Django format, it stopped giving error ORA-12505, however, now it is giving error ORA-28040.

Will I need to make any changes to the code? because I only made changes to the database data, putting it in the format that accepts the service_name.

Comment: Don't know what your issue is exactly from your question but these links should be helpful [Django docs - Oracle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#oracle-notes), [cx_Oracle quickstart](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#quick-start-cx-oracle-installation). I think you might not have the client libraries in your PATH.

Comment: Update your question to show the settings you are using e.g.  `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used Django but the configuration used to be like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME':     'myhost.example.com/orclpdb1',
    'USER':     'pythonhol',
    'PASSWORD': 'welcome',
  }
}
```

In this example the servicename is `oraclepdb`, and the `myhost.example.com` is the computer where the database is running.  The form `myhost.example.com/oralpdb1` is called the 'Easy Connect' syntax, see this article about the 19c syntax: [Oracle
Database 19c
Easy Connect
Plus](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-19c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf).